# Catching python subprocess exception

Tags: python, exception, subprocess

I have a python script where i am calling another script using subprocess as below.

```
        sp = subprocess.Popen("script.py --arg1 --arg2', cwd=GIVEN_PATH, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,  stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

        while sp.poll() is None:
            for out in iter(sp.stdout.readline,''):
                self.log(out.rstrip())
```

This is working fine for me but i want to get any exception from the script.py. I know we can get the retcode but i actually need to get the full exception information.

If script.py raises

```
         raise IOERROR("got an exception")
```

then i need to know this information. simailar way we get the sys.exc_info() etc.

is there a way i can do this?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: In addition to the answer below, it's useful to note that Python can call other python modules directly, without the need for a subprocess, which will allow you to catch Exceptions. This is what you should do in this case.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't get the `sys.exc_info()` from a subprocess -- by the time you're able to see the return code, objects in memory (including stack traces) of the child process are already gone.

What you can do is parse the text your subprocess writes to stderr, by providing a separate pipe for the stderr output and reading that. Assuming that your program never writes to stderr otherwise, the only text that will show up in that stream will be the error message and stack trace.

You'll want to be cautious with this approach, though, because if the process writes more text to stderr than you can buffer, you'll deadlock. The best solution is to have a separate thread to read from both stdout and stderr in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get `sys.exc_info()` then you could import the module and run functions from it instead of using `subprocess` module. You could use `multiprocessing` module if you need to run in a different process.

Another possibility is to use [`execfile()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#execfile) to run the module as a script in the same process as the parent script. If you want to pass command-line arguments to the script then you could manipulate `sys.argv` global list before calling `execfile()`.

Or you could combine `subprocess` + `execfile` methods: write a wrapper script that uses `execfile` to run the child script and serializes all exceptions (e.g., using `pickle`) and run the wrapper script using `subprocess` in your parent script. Capture stderr separately, to be able to unpickle child's exception info.

Comment: Thanks. The only problem is that i need to run the python file with arguments which is see is not possible on execfile()

Comment: @user2891472: I've updated the answer to mention how to pass command-line arguments to scripts started using `execfile()`