# What will be the best way to run a python script from another python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My use case : I am making a software that is able to run python scripts  with some test cases . Just like the online editor that you see in Competitive Programming Websites like [SPOJ](https://www.spoj.com/submit/TEST/)/ [Hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/solve-me-first/problem) /[Code Forces](https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/1426/F) etc.

I have searched SO and following are the solutions that I got for my problem :

1. Using `import` statement to import the script and then test on the functions.
2. Using `os.system` to run the script.
3. Using `subprocess.Popen()` to run the script.
4. Using `runpy` module.

I am a newbie and really don't know what will be the best option for my case.
I would love some guidance from the SO community.

Comment: It really depends on what kind of script you want to be working at. I would say `import` can already handle lots of structured data scripts easily. So unless you have a multiple platforms integrating with your data, `import` should be working just fine!

Comment: don't use `os.system()` otherwise all 3 other  options may be used depending on  specific features of your application.

Comment: related: [Getting return information from another python script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16877323/4279) Also, [Catching python subprocess exception](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27790745/4279) might be useful.

Comment: You should avoid `subprocess.Popen()` in favor of `subprocess.run()` if you can. If `os.system()` is acceptable then definitely `run` should be, too.  But generally don't run Python as a subprocess of Python if you don't have a particular reason (like forcing multiprocessing by crude means, or isolating e.g. signal handlers into one process without affecting another).

Comment: @RaghavGupta @jfs  , I used `import`. But now I am facing a logical error. The problem is that the `import` statements executes only once (even though you call it multiple times in the script)and so , suppose if someone had an error , and he modified the code , then also my script will not import the new code since the old code was imported earlier. Any tips and how to fix this?